# Yahoo Messenger In Proxy Connection

Tags: proxy

I woud like my Yahoo Messenger to be "Allow" in proxy connection for users. I manage to sort out some URL for YM.

http://*.yahoo.com*
https://login.yahoo.com
messenger.yahoo.com/*
httpvcs1.msg.yahoo.com/*
httpvcs2.msg.yahoo.com/*

In the same time, I would like to block user from accessing to Yahoo Mail. Any idea how to "Allow" Yahoo Messenger and "Deny" Yahoo Mail?

I did notice if I insert this URL (http://*.yahoo.com*) to proxy rule, its working fine for YM, but I can't achieved to block users access to Yahoo Mail.

Really appreciated for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly just block *.mail.yahoo.com and also any pop3/imap/smtp possible access.

Depending on the proxy server that you are using, you may even be able to further filter the actual URL request using some sort of regular expressions.

**Updated 2009-09-10**

Firewalls, as a rule, block ip addresses. That is not the way that you want to block access to this. You have a couple of other options.

1. Set up a transparent proxy and configure the rules there to block web connections to mail.yahoo.com domains and filter that based on url.
2. Poison your local DNS cache so that mail.yahoo.com resolves to a local web-server that shows that the site has been blocked from usage.

Comment: Added into proxy setting. But still cannot block users accessing to Yahoo Mail.

Comment: What do you mean by "added into proxy setting"?

Comment: Sorry, should be added into "ISA" Firewall Policy.

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer.